# Is the browser market share for StackExchange available?

Tags: discussion, browsers

I'm just curious if the StackExchange guys have any release of their browser share numbers?  It would be interesting to see what a widely used set of technical sites sees.

Comment: Here's a 2009 breakdown, in case you're interested in older data: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/

Comment: IE was 29% in 2009 - I'd love to know what it is today.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Well, that was SO only, right? I guess IE's share on the entire SE would be considerably higher.

Comment: @Dennis - sure, but I'm mostly interested in SO's traffic anyway.  I'd honestly be surprised if more than 10% of SO users use IE.

Comment: Also, I'm sure the Firefox and Chrome numbers are way different today. Three-year-old data on browser share is not very informative about today's trends.